# how to change the project name in the header of xcode files

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2

so recently I changed the name of my project by clicking on the target file of my xcode project inside the xcode developer suite. that changed almost everything accept a coupe of things.

One is the commented code at the top of each file still has the old name

```
//
//  myClass.m
//  oldname
//
//  Created by iMac on 3/01/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//
```

So I am wondering if there is a specific way of changing that old name from xcode.. or if i just have to go through each file and change them manually?

also the second issue is that in my file bundle some of the files still have to old name! so I am wondering how I change those without screwing up the application?

Comment: Write a perl or python script to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u want change "**MyCompanyName**" from each file.

Move to search navigator shortcut is:cmd+shift+enter

On the left there is button called find,choose replace there and then choose wit wat name u want to replace the string current string  "**MyCompanyName**".

All occurence of "**MyCompanyName**" will be replace with your new string in all project Files

Answer (score 0):

#### To update all existing files, simply:

1. Press **CMD+OPTION+SHIFT+F** to open the Find and Replace.
2. Type in your old company name and the new company name.
   [image: Xcode Find and Replace]
3. Press **Replace All**

#### To change the default value of **__MyCompanyName__** for new all new files created, you can do the following:

1. Select your project in Xcode (if the Inspector isn't visible, press *CMD+1*)
   [image: Xcode Inspector]
2. In the File Inspector along the right sidebar (if the File Inspector isn't visible, press  *CMD+OPTION+1*), edit the Organization entry under the Project Document section:
   [image: Xcode File Inspector]

All new classes that are added to the project will contain this new company name.